# print(xtable(myTable) does not print the expected output in the console

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I am trying to use R to convert some excel spreadsheet in Latex table to be used in publications.

I was following the vignette by Jonathan Swinton (see link below)

[The xtable Gallery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf)

In pag 10.

show this: [example code in the vignette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB9QV.png)

However when I enter this code I do not get to print the output table. Instead I got this:

```
> dat <- mtcars[1:3,1:6]
> x <- xtable(dat)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Aug 31 17:53:26 2016`
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
\hline
& mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt \\
\hline
Mazda RX4 & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.62 \\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.88 \\
Datsun 710 & 22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 & 3.85 & 2.32 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Why the table is not printed in the console?

Comment: R gives you Latex code. For you to get the table, you have to compile it using a Latex processor like Miktex. Another option is using R Sweave in RStudio.

Comment: Jilber I used star

Comment: Jilber I used stargazer to generate a output.tex file and I try to compile it in the mac terminal using tex:   **stargazer(Table1, summary=FALSE, float = TRUE, out="output2.tex",type="latex")**.............and then in the terminal I used : ......**pdflatex output2.tex**........but I got this error:      _

! LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined_